# requestAction shows a blank page in CakePHP 3.1

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.1

I am using CakePHP 3.1 and whenever I make use of `requestAction`, the page goes blank while I get an error in the console. The basic code is:-

```
$test = $this->requestAction('/dockets/find'.$articleList->id, [], ['return']);
```

While the dummy controller method is:-

```
function find($docket_id)
{
      return 0;
}
```

Whenever I include the code in any view file (.ctp file), I get a blank page. I also get a console error saying the current url cannot be found. The url works fine if I don't include the above code.

Comment: Take a closer look at the argument that you are passing, the path is lacking a separator after `find`.

Answer (score 0):

Your first argument for `requestAction` is wrong, there is a missing `/` after `find`. It should be:-

```
$test = $this->requestAction('/dockets/find/' . $articleList->id, [], ['return']);
```

Alternatively, you could call `requestAction` using a router array:-

```
$test = $this->requestAction(
    [
        'controller' => 'dockets', 
        'action' => 'find', 
        $articleList->id
    ], 
    [], 
    ['return']
);
```

Comment: I did it just as you mentioned here but the result is the same.

Comment: What does your Cake error logs say? Make sure you have `debug` on and perhaps try sending a message to the log in your `find()` method (*e.g.* `$this->log('find() method hit');`) to make sure the method is being triggered.